# Add event listener for HTML tag on Tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I'm working on my companies blog which we do through Tumblr. We have a menu bar on our mobile site where you press a menu button and through javascript a menu pops down. The menu button does not work on our Tumblr page's custom HTML but works everywhere else. I've found in the chrome debugger that there is an even listener for `div#menu-icon` from jquery.min.js:3 when the button works. This event listener does not appear in the Tumblr menu bar. How do I add this event listener to the Tumblr blog.

Here is the HTML for the working menu button:

```
<div id="menu-icon" class="menu">
  <div class="icon">Menu</div>
</div>
```

The HTML for the menu button in the Tumblr blog is the same, but I can't seem to get an event listener for `div#menu-icon` for the blog page. How would I do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For any HTML element, you can specify the action it will take when the user does something like click, using the `on***` attribute, where `***` is the action. E.g: `onclick=...`.

So for your element:

```
<div class="icon" onclick="dropdownMenu()">Menu</div>
```

This will execute the function `dropdownMenu()` when the user clicks the menu icon.

You can also attach event listeners with JavaScript, using `addEventListener()`:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="icon" id="menuIcon">Menu</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var icon = document.getElementById("menuIcon");
icon.addEventListener("click",function() {
    dropdownMenu()
});
```

This does exactly the same as the attribute approach but programmatically.